# Set the charset for Firebird connection from Pentaho DI

Tags: java, jdbc, pentaho, firebird, jaybird

I'm trying to set the connection `Charset` for my `Firebird` connection using `Pentaho DI` but still couldn't read the data in the right encoding.

I used many parameters like `encoding` , `charSet`,...etc but no luck.

[image]

[image]

Correct me what i have missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to use `encoding` with the **Firebird** name of the character set, or `charSet` with the **Java** name of the character set(*).

`WIN1256` is not a valid Java character set name, so the connection will fail. If you specify `charSet`, then you need to use the Java name `Cp1256` or - with Jaybird 2.2.1 or newer - `windows-1256`.

If this doesn't work then either Pentaho is not correctly passing connection properties, or your data is stored in a column with character set `NONE` in a different encoding than `WIN1256` (or worse: stored in a column with character set `WIN1256`, but the data is actually a different encoding).

*: Technically you can combine `encoding` and `charSet`, but it is only for special use cases where you want Firebird to read data in one character set, and have Jaybird interpret it in another character set.

Comment: I have tried both but no luck , i got the result like `ÒßÑíÇ ÇáÍÌÇæí : ãæÇá ÇáÔÌä` .. i think the data is stored in `ANSI` format . it contains arabic letter. when i used client like `FlameRobin` and set the charset `Windows-1256` it reads the `Arabic` data correctly .. I'm using Jaybird `2.2.10` with Pentaho

Comment: @Jason4Ever It sounds like Pentaho isn't passing the connection property. Which Pentaho version are you using?

Comment: I'm using kettle Pentaho CE v 5.0

Comment: Thx a lot brother , i replaced `Jaybird 2.2.10` with the default one from Pentaho `jaybird-2.1.6` and now it's working fine with setting `charSet = CP1256`

Comment: @Jason4Ever That is very curious, because I would expect Jaybird 2.2.10 to work as well. I will investigate that further, thanks.

Comment: @Jason4Ever I just tested Pentaho 5.0.1 and replaced jaybird-2.1.6.jar with jaybird-2.2.10.jar (JDK 1.8) and added connector-api-1.5.jar and it worked correctly. In both cases the Arabic characters are displayed correctly (I only used `charSet = Cp1256` under Options).

Comment: Thank you for your useful help and your following up . I'll try v2.2 again later.